# Memory initialization inside a loop: Segmentation fault on free

Tags: c, memory-leaks, free

I had written this rather big piece of code for an embedded system in which a function used to compute and assign values to a calloc structure in a loop. I ran into a bug in the code which took me some time to isolate and fix. I would like to see if someone else could point the bug out before sharing my experience if the need arises.

Declaration block:

```
int *arr;
int i, num;
printf("Enter number of elements: ");
scanf("%d", &num); //Assume num>=0
arr = calloc(num, sizeof(int));
if (arr == NULL)
    return;
i = num;
```

Which of the following block/blocks of code will throw an exception on calling free() and why?

```
for (i; i > 0; i--) {
    arr[num - i] = i;
}
free(arr);
```

OR

```
while (i--) {
    arr[num - i] = i;
}
free(arr);
```

Comment: And the second one will crash in a similar way: when `i == 1` at the top of the loop the `while` condition will succeed and also change `i` to 0; then the loop body will again attempt to write to `arr[num - 0]`.

Comment: Your loops look fine. Can you post a complete example that crashes? (ideone, codepad, whatever u like, or just here on SO)

Comment: @j_random_hacker: That's what I initially thought too, but the loops are okay.

Comment: @j_random_hacker `i > 0` and `i != 0` are the two break cases for the loops. None of the loops will run when `i == 0`.

Comment: @NiklasR: But in the second loop, if `i` is 1 and passes the test, it will *become* 0 immediately afterwards!

Comment: Codepad sample: http://codepad.org/5hH6Nl7O

Comment: @NiklasR For example the last loop: `i` will be `1` so the loop continues, then `i` is decremented so it's `0`, then the loop enters the loop body where `arr[num - 0]` is accessed.

Comment: You're right. Didn't see this obvious issue. Thanks

Comment: I can't help but feel that it would be more reliable to use: `for (i = 0; i < num; i++) arr[i] = num-i;` as people are much less likely to get the loop limits wrong.  Except that it does the assignments in reverse order compared with the original loops (which won't be detectable outside the loop itself), it produces the same result.

Answer (score 4):

Your second loop

```
while (i--) 
{
  arr[num - i] = i;
  printf("i = %d, num - i = %d, arr = %d\t", i, num - i, arr[num - i]);
}
```

causes the problem because of the postdecrement of i

you start out with `i == 10` so the first assignment is `arr[10 - 9] = 9`;
when `i` reaches `1` which is the last loop you get `arr[10 - 0] = 0`

and causes the assignment to write outside the array range 0..9

if you write the while loop like this it should work

```
do 
{
  arr[num - i] = i;
  printf("i = %d, num - i = %d, arr = %d\t", i, num - i, arr[num - i]);
}
while (--i);
```

Comment: @AndersK you are correct, the problem is in the while loop because of the behaviour of the postdecrement of i. In for loop, i decrements AFTER the loop statements are evaluated whereas in while loop, i decrements BEFORE the loop statements are evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

`for` is correct but problem in `while` loop

try this simple one :

```
    for(i=0;i<num;i++)
       arr[i]=i;
    free(arr);

    i=0;
    while(i<num)
       {
       arr[i]=i;
       i++;
      }
    free(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another problem is when user enters negative value for `num`, then your while loop can go infinite, as `-1` or any other negative value evaluates to `True`. It can also result in segmentation fault if `i` goes beyond boundaries (lower or upper) of the memory you allocated.

Comment: my bad, i should've specified num >= 0, I had those limit checks in my code but didn't add them here for the sake of conciseness.